# Define the number of components for PLSR when RMCEP doesn't stabilize

Tags: r, partial-least-squares

According to pls package, you can define the number of components of plsr using RMCEP.

I tried to do the same for the `df`, using this code

```
library(pls)
y <- as.matrix(df[,1])  
x <- as.matrix(df[,2:36])
df.pls <- mvr(y  ~ x , 
              ncomp = 10, 
              method = "oscorespls" , 
              validation = "LOO",
              scale = T)



> summary(df.pls)
Data:   X dimension: 15 35 
    Y dimension: 15 1
Fit method: oscorespls
Number of components considered: 10

VALIDATION: RMSEP
Cross-validated using 15 leave-one-out segments.
       (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps  6 comps  7 comps  8 comps  9 comps  10 comps
CV           0.284   0.1712   0.1990   0.1968   0.2247   0.2434   0.2812   0.3002   0.3573   0.4199    0.4718
adjCV        0.284   0.1692   0.1939   0.1922   0.2186   0.2365   0.2730   0.2913   0.3462   0.4066    0.4569

TRAINING: % variance explained
   1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps  6 comps  7 comps  8 comps  9 comps  10 comps
X    29.99    38.09    60.00    67.54    73.09    81.54    87.48    90.44    92.88     96.37
y    80.17    91.53    92.96    94.73    95.58    95.94    96.19    96.60    96.95     97.09
```

I got this plot for RMSEP

```
plot(RMSEP(df.pls), legendpos = "topright")
```

[image]

Comparing this plot to most of other RMCEP plots, I found it different. I usually find no higher RMCEP values with the increase in the number of components. Yet, in my case, RMCEP was higher for the 10th component than the 1st. I wonder why?

I think based on this plot, I should be using only one component.

Your suggestions and feedback will be highly appreciated.

**DATA**

In this [.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwgy9ulmyhk9nsl/df.csv?dl=0) file or below

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(dependent = c(0.86397454211987, 0.787954497352421, 
0.659691072486949, 0.946075761583277, 0.728654822779142, 0.62950913750375, 
0.220547032431762, 0.644444993765386, 0.0932051430418795, 0.770186377283592, 
0.649755817096116, 1.2620621832137, 0.813883734861209, 0.756789828278448, 
0.59333732933648), h_f = c(1041.41975308642, 15773.6534246575, 
9657.94383561644, 63956.4219178082, 197778.257534247, 35966.0917808219, 
36205.2424657534, 1846.36849315069, 13306.0657534247, 43568.8849315069, 
10483.9588477366, 4790.59726027397, 2604.7397260274, 8224.63561643836, 
39813.4506849315), h_QuFl = c(326.84540048392, 6557.27843422791, 
3261.10693883351, 24068.3321704268, 65529.9097068129, 15416.1394401651, 
15774.1168214205, 807.867897832351, 5522.27019290237, 16081.754959384, 
4612.86443524532, 1528.19683548948, 872.149503125132, 2895.91238144059, 
16903.29346385), h_BF = c(714.20985306257, 9213.90344104575, 
6396.83689678293, 39897.6782605484, 132174.271350296, 20549.9523406568, 
20431.1256443329, 1038.50059531833, 7778.31571189528, 27484.0175382703, 
5871.0944124913, 3262.40042478449, 1732.59022290227, 5326.69048213606, 
22910.1572210815), h_BFIh = c(0.686, 0.584, 0.662, 0.624, 0.668, 
0.571, 0.564, 0.562, 0.585, 0.631, 0.56, 0.681, 0.665, 0.648, 
0.575), h_Ra = c(6.17674897119342, 8.23551369863014, 7.08599315068493, 
5.4904187128457, 5.67950786402841, 5.41065841802916, 10.8220662100457, 
6.46143835616438, 18.9247260273973, 7.5814924297044, 5.31914951989026, 
7.76993150684932, 6.46958904109589, 7.10945205479452, 5.00932876712329
), h_PET = c(1.81097393689986, 1.65354452054795, 1.73058219178082, 
1.60063065391574, 1.80907762557078, 1.5343526292532, 1.92253424657534, 
1.80904109589041, 1.70986301369863, 1.7879956741168, 1.52829903978052, 
1.71349315068493, 1.59897260273973, 1.75561643835616, 1.62924200913242
), h_ER = c(5.40727023319616, 7.30272260273973, 6.2747602739726, 
4.80876195399328, 4.79026281075596, 4.77028281042863, 9.85849315068493, 
5.66623287671233, 17.9095205479452, 6.6363590483057, 4.69740740740741, 
6.97095890410959, 5.73369863013699, 6.27739726027397, 4.28383561643836
), m_a = c(11.77, 163.19, 135.39, 1261.88, 3191.83, 714.57, 278.69, 
26.58, 57.35, 401.28, 220.41, 53.36, 42.31, 77.35, 744.65), m_MeEl = c(549.25, 
328.67, 451.43, 343.41, 316.31, 362.37, 470.26, 280.56, 521.56, 
308.44, 362.23, 385.66, 312.29, 466.72, 288.97), m_MeSlPe = c(40.55, 
19.53, 28.77, 19.65, 22.82, 19.67, 38.77, 19.97, 39.85, 19.1, 
22.87, 22.55, 17.87, 29.46, 25.77), m_ElRa = c(0.32, 0.36, 0.45, 
0.39, 0.5, 0.42, 0.26, 0.41, 0.45, 0.34, 0.43, 0.47, 0.32, 0.38, 
0.43), m_DrDe = c(1.7, 1.73, 1.57, 1.68, 1.64, 1.65, 1.53, 1.74, 
1.62, 1.7, 1.63, 1.96, 1.81, 1.55, 1.53), c_C2 = c(6.38465773020042, 
9.78985858901589, 1.50356582433208, 7.65339989412654, 5.49752073990677, 
3.90059314867797, 5.9409185818413, 17.4685189240362, 1.3046321051485, 
5.8492626793834, 0, 22.6041793153936, 32.247470774266, 14.1062362886855, 
0.843516522957992), c_C3 = c(54.6485735221962, 47.7105460942601, 
87.9747102844327, 51.8527177042445, 52.9410050371843, 59.9933071920204, 
59.2002531727095, 6.30611865292691, 75.3578079057062, 47.5217195679834, 
73.9175281998161, 33.0000057897949, 17.7895691750417, 50.7102968695948, 
71.2739582196542), c_C4 = c(38.9667687476034, 42.499595316724, 
10.5217238912352, 40.3249893635017, 41.4876095819823, 35.8078469269088, 
34.8588282454492, 76.2253624230368, 23.3375599891453, 46.6290177526332, 
26.0824718001839, 44.3958148948115, 49.9629600506923, 35.1834668417197, 
27.8825252573878), d_D2 = c(6.38465773020042, 2.68799095824262, 
3.83422657879301, 3.10357361725961, 5.72101253575559, 0.582584426668564, 
0.310429629241765, 23.5236369297241, 0, 7.20751236564974, 0, 
16.9040756921581, 11.776860021365, 1.14463243233264, 5.41431731847442
), d_D3 = c(0, 6.00876004990636, 4.60414912318469, 21.2125301554554, 
20.5553248044751, 23.1934190213699, 16.0656101595563, 8.76631382526795, 
0.991353257873467, 2.82722923028608, 33.1101411654781, 1.4597129328763, 
27.0133941457253, 7.18460363621184, 34.038045603972), d_D4 = c(29.812474631149, 
16.9997855063674, 16.9484733602449, 12.2962240035803, 19.4487078537099, 
13.3162195315644, 39.7673906398948, 0, 71.0194979738029, 21.4164343190374, 
23.4607809727846, 5.70504485786588, 5.4888828491522, 11.8151517616597, 
25.9226181415465), d_D5 = c(63.8028676386506, 74.3034634854837, 
74.6131509377774, 63.3876722237047, 54.2749548060594, 62.9077770203972, 
43.8565695713072, 67.7100492450079, 27.9891487683237, 68.5488240850268, 
43.4290778617374, 75.9311665170997, 55.7208629837575, 79.8556121697958, 
34.6250189360071), l_Da = c(22.2987231970424, 37.302281222996, 
0, 15.6888076579869, 15.3143227640784, 7.49552886039105, 9.21111717074486, 
15.6483412661417, 1.09281136009292, 34.6450027695119, 0.180628929489219, 
43.0778604483166, 35.4442243795419, 22.3103188721025, 1.69075281628809
), l_NaCo = c(65.1901939669953, 16.9440437901174, 16.8592486381856, 
10.0217003815836, 16.9178216725931, 7.27861971152794, 66.3473082501395, 
26.9484833920213, 64.9511228483726, 19.8836148068671, 4.13435918931213, 
32.9788279487656, 22.9070497052634, 35.5649600755622, 11.3521194977445
), l_ShBe = c(10.7608030609987, 42.8900057987031, 80.663402529751, 
69.9119944821054, 63.7520715780007, 81.8269148029647, 23.1058374218561, 
52.3253889206384, 32.7228187389004, 43.0244133098626, 90.9194088664656, 
22.7834238897341, 39.6658979608829, 39.4195030936271, 81.3124392127133
), Mr_Co = c(0, 0, 55.1128728093047, 6.51090929661756, 7.75041439460692, 
7.95893058086494, 4.14643495765247, 0, 0, 2.54938917987072, 20.7580709729255, 
0, 0.471612101548274, 0, 11.324878993859), Mr_GRAv = c(35.3896058163273, 
30.7432333308418, 5.10851905044963, 39.847735861398, 30.6826416725748, 
31.7526597888325, 19.4881703291849, 32.2650320691635, 12.3518678893064, 
39.099244961592, 7.05710760397929, 58.8850326871133, 50.9556529985623, 
41.3555074493459, 11.2694297654175), Mr_GREy = c(9.88107227563547, 
27.8058034065098, 7.06352142365074, 6.11279891418493, 13.8435635061977, 
3.3341124261228, 68.1839854780714, 27.5842838556726, 77.3296388036071, 
25.7336688950093, 10.8093669952665, 14.9315696591391, 19.6728001455373, 
3.66489820552796, 1.35155474262874), Mr_Mu = c(0, 27.9788730214221, 
22.4789874821358, 10.9120473953551, 28.3402024501966, 10.44521479672, 
8.18140923509129, 0, 10.1563537553917, 26.509122106797, 13.9141292330255, 
0, 15.2986691974923, 0, 66.5277988300636), Mr_Sa = c(54.7293219080373, 
0, 0, 34.630486683079, 16.1537362551322, 43.2860322394116, 0, 
40.1506840751639, 0, 0, 45.0619898493789, 26.1833976537477, 13.6012655568597, 
54.7388963413616, 4.60393247565709), s_SaLo = c(0, 3.62885344924762, 
49.7156992962877, 22.8742965465896, 16.1037497470103, 26.4108812066677, 
0, 8.76631382526795, 0, 2.28989887729153, 41.204133609971, 1.4597129328763, 
24.7165698755149, 0, 22.1203660572375), s_SiLo = c(68.3924324838086, 
46.7825172630918, 40.2918029150206, 50.9952195120652, 52.4616283965265, 
49.8656534812195, 29.2832265709446, 73.9920650538172, 17.3120134354451, 
47.8438174044157, 35.5069030606913, 69.5515837880942, 62.4089302957283, 
70.6441053507101, 61.3184871234248), s_St = c(9.34306648617202, 
16.9407115250502, 0, 3.02375098621997, 7.49142545780987, 0.739987935905543, 
47.9639272491623, 0, 45.1441255322013, 15.8949013302606, 2.37812587269736, 
4.51166909866183, 1.22573367622539, 1.41402832539501, 0.0517684668983939
), s_sSiLo = c(0, 10.2631744532951, 3.69657384646686, 3.51661128643063, 
5.38382097572785, 4.32919720682223, 17.0908901169596, 0, 26.3981021895912, 
10.2162013196148, 1.64750150735275, 0, 0.3886506275644, 11.6553395492559, 
0.672088258465062), Sr_Li = c(0, 0, 1.70442568792041, 5.71976303452223, 
5.0036595147534, 6.56182424061139, 4.14643495765247, 0, 2.17838680427836, 
2.86071234634266, 3.2464151051141, 0, 0.471612101548274, 0, 0.724170451915613
), Sr_SaLoSi = c(31.4915152861977, 13.0626789594875, 4.58852637794785, 
8.07133532113299, 12.3784892438516, 1.41827358332991, 6.77359973391309, 
28.7019160437988, 0.147389283434159, 20.7639813245479, 4.55174136965654, 
40.9469057406407, 34.0553180610046, 0, 10.1596460774595), Sr_SaCoCoTe = c(0, 
27.9788730214221, 21.8693540906945, 5.7796242808183, 21.9582513650753, 
1.38173157278083, 8.18140923509129, 0, 6.30678806617604, 25.9258663994387, 
4.4796460797524, 0, 15.2986691974923, 0, 48.1840998259004), Sr_SaMu = c(9.88107227563547, 
15.9350047162996, 0, 1.62740092981472, 10.4709347286845, 0, 68.1839854780714, 
27.5842838556726, 77.3296388036071, 20.9061094414991, 0, 14.9315696591391, 
19.6728001455373, 3.66489820552796, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .Names = c("dependent", 
"h_f", "h_QuFl", "h_BF", "h_BFIh", "h_Ra", "h_PET", "h_ER", "m_a", 
"m_MeEl", "m_MeSlPe", "m_ElRa", "m_DrDe", "c_C2", "c_C3", "c_C4", 
"d_D2", "d_D3", "d_D4", "d_D5", "l_Da", "l_NaCo", "l_ShBe", "Mr_Co", 
"Mr_GRAv", "Mr_GREy", "Mr_Mu", "Mr_Sa", "s_SaLo", "s_SiLo", "s_St", 
"s_sSiLo", "Sr_Li", "Sr_SaLoSi", "Sr_SaCoCoTe", "Sr_SaMu"))
```

Comment: With this low number of observations you can practically get increasing or misleading RMSEP. Actually, as the number of components increases, the chances of overfitting increases which may be somewhat evident from a RMSEP vs ncomp plot obtained by LOOCV. Another possibility is that PLSR fails to model this data. How about obtaining a test set to evaluate the success of the model?

Comment: @theGD
Thanks for your time and help. Could you please clarify what do you mean by a test to evaluate the model success?

Comment: A set of samples which are not used for model building but whose responses to be predicted are known. So, when you predict them with the model you built, you can compare the predicted values with real ones to see how well your model performs and see if there is overfitting.